# Regular Expression Can't Match

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string:

`8 0 0 . Item s Payable in Connection w ith Loan`

I am trying to match it using the following regular expression:

`^8\\s*0\\s*0\\.`

What I believe this regular expression is saying is:

1. 8 has to be at the beginning of the string
2. There can be any amount of spaces between 8 and a 0
3. There can be any amount of spaces between the first 0 and the second 0
4. The last 0 must be followed by a period .

However in my application, this does match my string. Can any one rpvodie assistance on why it might not be matching. I am using Java.

Comment: please rpvodie some code and a spellcheck

Comment: I see what you did there...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there's a space between you last `0` and your period.  your regular expression doesn't allow for that.   that's why it's failing.

try

```
 "^8\\s*0\\s*0\\s*\\."
```